# HTML table Width = "100%" still didn't fit to window size in ASP.Net

Tags: html, asp.net, css

I have a html table for displaying data. I have the typical width="100%"; but it did not work. Here is what my page looks like and my CSS/HTML styling. How can I fix it to auto fit the screen?

Code:

```
<table style="border: medium solid #FFFFFF; background-color: #000000; position: fixed;"
             border="3" width="100%";>
```

Comment: Which browser(s) and which version(s)?

Comment: VS 2010 and Chrome but it shouldn't matter right? Browser wise.

Comment: This table is not inside any other element with a smaller width?

Comment: @Nacho Nope just the cells inside.

Comment: If it's inside a div with a smaller width, it wil only fit to 100% the size of it's container.  When you hit F12 to inspect the DOM, do you see it nested inside of anything at all?

Comment: Everyone is overlooking the obvious here. Check below...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make sure your `body` element has `padding` and `margin` set to `0`

[Without setting this](http://jsfiddle.net/66FhF/) vs [when this is set](http://jsfiddle.net/66FhF/1/)

```
html, body{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
```

Comment: So make a style for it? and it have the values as demonstrated?

Comment: If not set already, you should add the above to your CSS as written and see if it works (it should)

Comment: I'm still new to this and am having issues delineating between the HTML and CSS.

Comment: If your CSS is inline, within your HTML page at the top you should have a <style> tag, place the above after this. Otherwise you will have a <link> tag in the <head> of your page with your .css file linked, add the above to that file

Comment: Alternatively, find your body tag, in your HTML and change to e.g.: <body style='margin:0;padding:0;'>

Comment: Yes! Thank you for you help and patience with me I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Add this CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0
}
```

Because the default margin for `body` element in not `0`

Answer (score 0):

add these lines in your style

```
*{margin:0; padding:0;}
```

Comment: This CSS rule is not recommended! because may cause some deformation to other elements

Comment: Actually I highly recommend it to increase cross browser compatibility provided it is done at the start of a project, doing it mid project could have undesired effects.

Comment: @DreamTeK This makes some deformation to elements which have their own default margin or padding

Comment: @ABFORCE this is standard and cross browser compatible practice

Answer (score 0):

You have 100% width plus a border. This is greater than 100%.

**HTML**

```
<table class="tbl" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
```

**CSS**

```
.tbl{
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    border:3px solid #fff;
    background:#000;
    box-sizing:border-box; /* causes item size to include border and padding */
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box; /*for browser compatibility*/
}
```